# Opensips-cli -x command not working in opensips 3.3

Tags: voip, opensips

Recently I am working on upgrading my opensips version manually from 2.2 to 3.3.

Upgradation is done from my side but in old opensips(2.2) I was able to show registered user(SIP) using **opensipsctl ul show** command but in new version 3.3 opensipsctl is deprecated(I guess not sure).

So I am trying to get details using **opensips-cli** but I didn't find out correct command for show register and show dump list, I try to follow below link but did not find correct command.

https://www.opensips.org/Documentation/Interface-CoreMI-3-0

Also, my opensips-cli -x command not working giving the below error. (**mi_fifo** module loaded correctly)

```
# opensips-cli -o output_type=yaml -x mi uptime
ERROR: cannot access fifo file /tmp/opensips_fifo: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/opensips_fifo'
ERROR: starting with Linux kernel 4.19, processes can no longer read from FIFO files 
ERROR: that are saved in directories with sticky bits (such as /tmp)
ERROR: and are not owned by the same user the process runs with. 
ERROR: To fix this, either store the file in a non-sticky bit directory (such as /var/run/opensips), 
ERROR: or disable fifo file protection using 'sysctl fs.protected_fifos=0' (NOT RECOMMENDED)
```

**/tmp/opensips_fifo** file also created correctly.

```
# ls -l /tmp/opensips_fifo
prw-rw-rw- 1 opensips opensips 0 Dec 29 06:52 /tmp/opensips_fifo
```

Using **opensips-cli** command I am able to create **database** and add **table** but not able to perform **-x** command.

Can anyone help me to find out a command for show register and show dump list also any suggestion related -x command not working on opensips-cli.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and i found the following:
if you state in the opensips-cli.cfg file that the fifo_file is located at `/tmp/opensips_fifo`, it will produce this error, try changing this setting to `/var/run/opensips/opensips_fifo`